# Keep menu & content box same width

Tags: html, css

I would like to get your suggestions on what I should do.

I am trying to keep the navigation bar and the content box on a website I'm working on the exact same width. I've tried adjusting using both *percentages* and *pixels*. It looks perfect on my laptop, but it does not on a larger monitor or on my cell phone browser. Any ideas of what I can do?

You can view the website at http://www.shaunmichaelmusic.com/new

Thanks in advance for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to avoid using too many discrete boxing and positioning rules when creating something like this. It would make your design either distorted or inflexible when a user simply resizes the browser.

A better approach would be something like this: http://jsbin.com/abidej

Feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your menu & style CSS sheets to: position: relative and width: both the same either the 450 or 480px

Comment: For whatever reason, that pushed the navigation bar below the content box, and didn't make them the same width.  I left it that way in case you wanted to take a peep at it.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The `#nav` is styled completely with `px` but the `#contentbox` is styled with `px` and `%`.

I would stick to one unit of measurement. Either switch the padding to `padding:14px` or convert *everything* to `%`.